# How to display a content of file in tcl notebook frame

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am writing a tcl notebook code to show Errors in first tab and Warnings in other.
However this Error and warnings needs to be displayed in frame area of tcl notebook, i tried few options but it didn't work.
These errors and warnings needs to be read from some external file.

errors.txt file looks like this

```
Errors DFF_X9ATH failing
Error DFFX_A9th_XC is faiing
```

Here is my code, plzz guide me how to open Error.txt and warn.txt in tkk frame area.

```
#!/usr/bin/wish

package require Tk


set file "errors.txt"
ttk::notebook .n  -width 800 -height 800
ttk::frame .n.f1; 
ttk::frame .n.f2; 
.n add .n.f1 -text "Errors"
.n add .n.f2 -text "Warnings"
pack [label .n.f1.f2 -background red -foreground white -text "Errors"]
pack [label .n.f2.f2 -background red -foreground white -text "Warnings"]
pack .n
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option would be to use text widgets instead of labels. When you've packed the text widgets, you can add text using `<widget path> insert end <file content>`, with the parts inside `<>` replaced by the relevant parts in your code.